# Работа с serialport (FTDI) из bash

Tags: linux, bash, serial

Linux, Raspbian 8. 
В USB воткнут преобразователь USB-CAN. Появляется в системе как /dev/ttyUSB0

Сам преобразователь и устройство за ним точно рабочие.

Требуется послать в порт 4 байта, подождать 200мс и получить ответ в 4 байта.

попробовал вот так:

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT="/dev/ttyUSB0"
stty -F $PORT 9600

printf '\x0b\x00\x06\x80' > $PORT
sleep 0.2
read -rn 4 data < $PORT
echo $data
```

На строке с read все зависает. Видимо не получает не каких данных в ответ. Пробовал менять на 1 входящий символ. Но похоже в ответ полная тишина.

Правильно ли я вообще работаю с портом? В какую сторону копать?

**UPDATE 10.03**

что-то нахимичил

1. теперь все что, отправляю в порт прилетает обратно. Именно то, что отправил но не то что ожидаю от оборудования
2. еще странная вещь

   ```
   $ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
   stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: Неприменимый к данному устройству ioctl
   $ setserial /dev/ttyUSB0
   Cannot get serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device
   ```

Comment: попробуйте читать по одному байту (чтобы понять, что в порт вообще что-нибудь поступает). или вместо *read* запустите в соседнем терминале `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: да, попробуйте просто в одной консоли `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`, а в соседней `echo "something" > /dev/ttyUSB0`. Соответственно, считается ли строка?

Comment: А почему нельзя читать сразу без sleep?

Comment: по документации на оборудование. Там сказано, что окончанием приема данных является пауза в передаче не менее 200мс и начинается ответная передача. Я попробовал без паузы и с разными паузами как большими так и меньшими. Результат такой же. У меня складывается впечатление, что все что я отправляю в порт не доходит.

Comment: вопрос был в правильных параметрах настройки stty подобрал подходящие, теперь все работает. Всем спасибо.

Comment: так пауза считается по передаче, о том что вы начали приём устройство и не знает

Answer (score 2):

Для передачи двоичных данных у меня работает следующая настройка порта:

```
stty raw -echo -onlcr -iexten 9600 -F /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Для usb-serial-преобразователя имя устройства после очередного переподключения иногда может непредсказуемо поменяться с ttyUSB0 на ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2 и т.д.